# Unit Testing code built with MVVMCross SQLite Plugin

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I'm currently building a Xamarin.Forms project using MVVMCross. In order to test my platform specific code I am using [Nunit.Xamarin](https://github.com/nunit/nunit.xamarin) which features an app that run tests on device.

This test app is a forms app but doesn't use MVVMCross and I haven't had any luck setting it up to use MVVMCross due to the fact the Application class loads an App of type *NUnit.Runner.App* whereas MVVMCross requires *MvxFormsApp*.

I want to test this class the saves and loads user data from an SQLite Database:

```
public class DataStorageService : IDataStorageService
{
    private readonly SQLiteConnection _connection;

    public User UserData
    {
      get { return _connection.Table<User>().FirstOrDefault(); }
      set { _connection.InsertOrReplace(value); }
    }

    public DataStorageService(IMvxSqliteConnectionFactory factory)
    {
      _connection = factory.GetConnection(DataStorageConstants.LocalDatabaseName);
      _connection.CreateTable<User>();
    }
  }
```

I want to actually test that it saves and loads from a local SQLite database so I don't want to mock the *IMvxSqliteConnectionFactory*. I tried installing MVVMCross and the SQLite plugin into the project and then passing in the Android implementation of the connection factory but that repeatedly threw a typeloadexception.

Any ideas as to how I can set up this test with MVVMCross (or are there alternatives?) and dependency injection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible :) The important stuff happens in the `MvxSplashScreenActivity`. The `MvxFormsApp` is basically empty. So we don't have to care. Example Code: https://github.com/smstuebe/stackoverflow-answers/tree/master/mvx-android-test-app

1. Create a nunit Test app project
2. `Install-Package MvvmCross.StarterPack -Version 4.1.4`
3. Get rid of `Views` folder
4. Install the SQLite plugin
5. Reference your Core project
6. `Install-Package MvvmCross.Forms.Presenter -Version 4.1.4`
7. Remove `MainLauncher = true` from `MainActivity`
8. Adust `Setup` to return your core project's `App`

```cs
protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp()
{
    return new MyApp.Core.App();
}
```

9. Change SplashScreen to ([source](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Forms/blob/master/MvvmCross.Forms.Presenter.Droid/SplashScreen.cs.txt))

```cs
[Activity(MainLauncher = true
, Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash"
, NoHistory = true
, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class SplashScreen
: MvxSplashScreenActivity
{
    public SplashScreen()
        : base(Resource.Layout.SplashScreen)
    {
    }

    private bool _isInitializationComplete;
    public override void InitializationComplete()
    {
        if (!_isInitializationComplete)
        {
            _isInitializationComplete = true;
            StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
        }
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Android.OS.Bundle bundle)
    {
        Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        Forms.ViewInitialized += (object sender, ViewInitializedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.View.StyleId))
            {
                e.NativeView.ContentDescription = e.View.StyleId;
            }
        };

        base.OnCreate(bundle);
    }
}
```

10. Write a test like

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class TestClass
{
    [Test]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        var service = Mvx.Resolve<IDataStorageService>();
        Assert.IsNull(service.UserData);
    }
}
```

11. Enjoy the awesomeness of MvvmCross